# Why is the style not applied to the child nodes of a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, class, parent-child

For a searchfield I add dinamically div childnodes like this:

```html
    <div id="recommand" class="recommand"></div>
```

```js
    data.result.forEach(function(entry) {
            let cont: rcommand;
            cont.username = entry[0];
            const x = document.getElementById('recommand') as HTMLInputElement;
            const blocktoinsert = document.createElement( 'div' );
            blocktoinsert.innerHTML = cont.username;
            x.appendChild(blocktoinsert);
          });
```

```css
    .recommand div{
      background-color:red;
    }
```

but the background color is not applied. Any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: It's because JavaScript works in HTML when you surround it with <script> tag same as css code but diferent tag. XD

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mises! The script works fine, everything is done in an angular component function, the only problem is the styl of the div

Comment: I assume that `data` is the result from an AJAX call. Is it actually returning data? Are the child `div`s actually being inserted into the page, with content inside them?

Comment: As I said the divs are shown with no background

Comment: The selector you have doesn't select the div with class `recommand`, it selects the child div that is inside an element with class `recommand`

Comment: Could you paste what the resulting code is, from DevTools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a style according to html you targeting wrong way.

**This is correct:**

```css
div.recommand {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**If above work not ok try this:**

`.recommand > div`  Selects all `<div>` elements where the parent is a `.recommand` element.

`.recommand + div`  Selects all `<div>` elements that are placed immediately after `.recommand` elements.

> Write comment if I'm wrong.

Comment: That is correct if they want the parent div and all child divs to be impacted. If they want just the child divs styled, `.recommand div` is correct, or at least one way to do it. But it appears that is what they wanted..

Comment: @NathanMiller He did want to just target class. May be he needed only a strong chain targeting. this is weak target `.recommand {...` this is stronger `div.recommand {..` and this is incorect acording to html template `.recommand div {...` Becouse he dont have any `<div>` inside.

Comment: The Javascript he has runs through a result set and adds (likely multiple) `<div>`s to the one existing `<div>`. So there aren't any in the code he gave us, but there would be after his JS ran, which is why I was asking to make sure they were being inserted.

Comment: @NathanMiller I edited if he need help he will come back. XD